# Mongoose Aggregate with $last on Original Array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

I am using mongoose aggregation to return a custom query from a database, as shown below. Under the `$addFields` stage, I am generating some custom "stats" that can help with pagination client-side, such as how many documents in total, remaining number of documents, and page number.

I'd like to add a "cursor" field to this stage, which would be the `createdAt` field of the last element of the array queried. The `createdAt` field is guaranteed to be present.

To do this, I was thinking of using the `$last` operator, but can not figure out what to pass as the second argument. The documentation shows examples that have arrays as part of each document... not the original array of documents.

Thanks for any help or direction you might be able to point me toward! -- Here is my aggregation call:

For context, `params` is passed into the function, which contains the model to be queried.

```
  const documents = await params.model.aggregate([
    { $match: params.filters },
    { $sort: params.options.sort },
    {
      $facet: {
        [params.model.modelName]: [{ $limit: params.options.limit }],
        stats: [
          {
            $count: 'count',
          },
          {
            $addFields: {
              cursor: {$last: `$${params.model.modelName}.createdAt`}, // THIS IS THE FIELD I AM TRYING TO GET TO FUNCTION
              total: totalCount,
              remaining: {
                $cond: {
                  if: {
                    $gt: [{ $subtract: ['$count', params.options.limit] }, 0],
                  },
                  then: { $subtract: ['$count', params.options.limit] },
                  else: 0,
                },
              },
              page: {
                $ceil: {
                  $divide: [
                    {
                      $subtract: [
                        totalCount,
                        {
                          $cond: {
                            if: {
                              $gt: [
                                { $subtract: ['$count', params.options.limit] },
                                0,
                              ],
                            },
                            then: {
                              $subtract: ['$count', params.options.limit],
                            },
                            else: 0,
                          },
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                    params.options.limit,
                  ],
                },
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ]);
```

Here is the example array of documents:

```
[
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("61cb2d94fc13ae690f000419"),
      name: 'Nicolette',
      age: 22,
      married: false,
      createdAt: 2020-12-29T20:06:41.000Z
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("61cb2d93fc13ae690f0000da"),
      name: 'Ranice',
      age: 33,
      married: false,
      createdAt: 2020-02-20T08:49:46.000Z
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("61cb2d93fc13ae690f0000cf"),
      name: 'Morganica',
      age: 18,
      married: true,
      createdAt: 2020-01-22T12:26:59.000Z
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("61cb2d94fc13ae690f00046d"),
      name: 'Eunice',
      age: 59,
      married: true,
      createdAt: 2019-08-20T04:06:58.000Z
    }
  ]
```

Comment: What is the "original array of documents" ?

Comment: Hey Alex - Thanks for checking this out with me. I added the documents above --

Comment: Do I understand right that the array you added is what you have  in the ` [params.model.modelName]` after the $facet stage? Or is it the whole collection?

Comment: So in the facet section, it is finding documents that match criteria, and paginating them.  It returns 4 documents (like so above). I want then to just find the last of these documents, and return the createdAt field as the curosr

Comment: You need to to do that on the next stage after $facet.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks so much - I'll research into this - if you have any documentation references that would be extremely helpful